# wordpress - replace ... with read more

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to replace `[...]` with read more link:

```
function replace_excerpt($content) {
    return str_replace('[...]',
           '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">Read More →</a>',
           $content
    );
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_excerpt');
```

I don't know why it's not work for me!

I call the excerpt with this:

```
<?php
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        the_content();
    } else {
        the_excerpt();
    }
?>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: there are many wordprees Q in stackoverflow and you just see this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">...Read More</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

Comment: @newbie Cool! I`ll appreciate if you`ll select it as a correct answer. :)

Comment: it's have time limit i select it as soon as possible, Thank you.